# AES ShiftRow Confusion

Tags: aes, reference-request, implementation

I'm implementing AES and I'm getting confused in the `ShiftRows` step. So far, my key expansion and `SubBytes` works and I get the same output as specified by the NIST publication.

For the `ShiftRows` Steps, if we refer to the test vector below from NIST, the output is incorrect according to this:

[image: this]

Round 1, [from NIST page 35:](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
state:      63cab7040953d051cd60e0e7ba70e18c <-- SubBytes() 
state:      6353e08c0960e104cd70b751bacad0e7 <-- ShiftRows()
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

If we consider the matrix below:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
S_{00} & S_{01} & S_{02} & S_{03} \\  
S_{10} & S_{11} & S_{12} & S_{13} \\  
S_{20} & S_{21} & S_{22} & S_{23} \\  
S_{30} & S_{31} & S_{32} & S_{33} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\texttt{63} & \texttt{ca} & \texttt{b7} & \texttt{04} \\  
\texttt{09} & \texttt{53} & \texttt{d0} & \texttt{51} \\
\texttt{cd} & \texttt{60} & \texttt{e0} & \texttt{e7} \\
\texttt{ba} & \texttt{70} & \texttt{e1} &  \texttt{8c} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the output is clearly different.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\texttt{63} & \texttt{ca} & \texttt{b7} & \texttt{04} \\  
\texttt{53} & \texttt{d0} & \texttt{51} & \texttt{09} \\
\texttt{e0} & \texttt{e7} & \texttt{cd} & \texttt{60} \\
\texttt{8c} & \texttt{ba} & \texttt{70} & \texttt{e1} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The state must be written/read along the columns:

63cab7040953d051cd60e0e7ba70e18c $\mapsto$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
63 & 09 & cd & ba \\
ca & 53 & 60 & 70 \\
b7 & d0 & e0 & e1 \\
04 & 51 & e7 & 8c
\end{bmatrix}
$

shift rows $\mapsto$ $
\begin{bmatrix}
63 & 09 & cd & ba \\
53 & 60 & 70 & ca \\
e0 & e1 & b7 & d0 \\
8c & 04 & 51 & e7 
\end{bmatrix}
$ $\mapsto$ 6353e08c0960e104cd70b751bacad0e7

See Figure 3 in FIPS SP 197, 3.4 (http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf).

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but the way it is labelled seems to indicate otherwise. Damn, I will have to fix my implementation now...